# Send packet (PCAP, WLAN, C) to reciever, recieving without connection

Tags: c, linux, wifi, pcap, radiotap

I plan to use Wi-Fi by radio to navigate my drone.
I want so send packets from laptop to the drone. Currently I can send packets out, but only when the Wi-Fi card is in monitor mode.

```
static const u8 u8aRadiotapHeader[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, // <-- radiotap version
    0x0c, 0x00, // <- radiotap header length
    0x04, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, // <-- bitmap
    0x22, // <-- rate
    0x0, //<-- tx power
    0x18, 0x00  //<-- antenna 
};

static u8 u8aIeeeHeader[] = {
    0x08, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0x13, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66,
    0x13, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66,
    0x10, 0x86,
};
```

Is it possible to set up my headers so that the Wi-Fi card will receive the packet without being in monitor mode, and if so, how can I achieve it?
Or am I forced to filter all packets in air?

Regards,
Kokos Bot.

My systems:

Sender: Linux 64-bit with PCAP for my sending program in C

Reciever: R-Pi2

I use TL-WN722N on both the sending and receiving sides.

Comment: is there a reason you must use C? and please mention the programming language. It is not specific to Kali Linux (it's just Linux + preinstalled tools) so I changed the Kali Linux tag to just Linux.

Comment: Well i only learned c/c++ and my inspiration programm code ist c too.
https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/

Comment: One tip for you: please use proper spelling and grammar. Not doing so WILL attract downvotes. This is a common noob mistake. imagine this was GitHub or your résumé.

Comment: Not enough information. Learn to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please use code formatting. Select the code and click `{}` in the toolbar.

Comment: Normally, I would copyedit for you (with my no-approval-require privilege), but I want you to learn. So please copyedit it now. [edit]

Comment: Yes, i try to improve my english. I read the info page. The {} tool expect the }; every time...

Comment: Select ALL the code. Including `}`. I'll copyedit you now.

Comment: also, use the preview!

Comment: tell what is "monitor mode". We don't know enough.

Comment: I'm removing unnecessary info to create a [mcve]. Read that guide.

Comment: Look over my changes to learn how to format questions in the future. Click "edited ..... ago"

Comment: there's gotta be a preexisting library for this.

Comment: Ok, i read "edited ... ago".

Answer (score 0):

The monitor mode allows to send and receive arbitrary packets without association.
If your sender and receiver are not connected you can send raw packets using this mode only.